# How to create a circle in Java using the distance formula

Tags: java

I have to create the flag of Japan using expo, but I cannot use the `drawCircle()` method. I was told to use the distance formula instead to create the circle, how do I do this?

This is what United States Flag method looked like, my flag of Japan code should look like this:

```
public static void flagofUSA (Graphics g)
{
    Expo.setBackground(g,Expo.black);
    for (int d = 1; d <= numDots; d++)
    {
        int x = Expo.random(0,1000);      
        int y = Expo.random(0,650);  
        // random y value of each dot

        fiftyStars(g);

        if (x < 400 &&  y< 350)                      
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.blue);

        if (x > 400 &&  y< 50)                      
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);

        if (x > 400 &&  y< 100 && y >50)                      
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);

        if (x > 400 &&  y< 150 && y >100)                       
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);

        if (x > 400 &&  y< 200 && y >150)                      
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);

        if (x > 400 &&  y< 250 && y >200)                       
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);

        if (x > 400 &&  y< 300 && y >250)                    
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);

        if (x > 400 &&  y< 350 && y >300)                     
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);

        if (y< 400 && y >350)                      
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);

        if ( y< 450 && y >400)                      
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);

        if ( y< 500 && y >450)                       
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);

        if ( y< 550 && y >500)                      
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);

        if ( y< 600 && y >550)                       
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);

        if ( y< 650 && y >600)                       
            Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);

        drawDot(g,x,y);
    }
    showName(g,"USA");
}
```

Comment: The general equation for a 2D circle is `(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2`, for a circle centered at `(a, b)`.  At the x and y extremes, by inspection you can see what the values would be for a given radius.  You may simply scan x and y space and figure out which values fit the circle.  Then, draw points at these positions.

Comment: Not sure how the USA flag code is relevant to the question of drawing a circle.  But since you're doing this by generating random dots and deciding what colour they should be, all you have to do is test whether `(x-a)*(x-a) + (y-b)*(y-b)` is greater than or less than `r*r` every time you draw a dot.